# Convert string representations of sparse vectors into Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

I have a vector `vec` where each element is a string representation of a sparse vector.
The output I want is a Pandas `DataFrame` with the following characteristics:

> **index**: `vec` index
>   **columns**: sparse vector indices
>   **values**: sparse vector values

The sparse vectors are encoded with the format `<feature_index>:<feature_value>`, and records are separated by a single space.

Here are a few rows of example data:

```
vec = ["70:1.0000 71:1.0000 83:1.0000",
       "3:2.0000 8:2.0000 9:3.0000",
       "3:3.0000 185:1.0000 186:1.0000",
       "3:1.0000 8:1.0000 289:1.0000"]
```

And here's my expected output:

```
          185     186     289       3      70      71       8      83       9
index                                                                        
0         NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  1.0000  1.0000     NaN  1.0000     NaN
1         NaN     NaN     NaN  2.0000     NaN     NaN  2.0000     NaN  3.0000
2      1.0000  1.0000     NaN  3.0000     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3         NaN     NaN  1.0000  1.0000     NaN     NaN  1.0000     NaN     NaN
```

I have a working solution using [`from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html) and [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), but it seems clumsy and inefficient:

```
import pandas as pd

dense = pd.DataFrame()

for i, row in enumerate(vec):
    tups = []
    for entry in row.split(): 
        tups.append(tuple([x for x in entry.split(':')]))

    dense = pd.concat([dense,
                       (pd.DataFrame
                          .from_records(tups, 
                                        index=[i]*len(tups), 
                                        columns=['key','val'])
                          .reset_index()
                          .pivot(index='index', 
                                 columns='key', 
                                 values='val')
                       )
                     ])
```

**Can anyone suggest a cleaner approach, ideally one that makes better use of Pandas functionality?**
The actual dataset I'm working with is rather large, so I'd like to take advantage of the performance optimizations in native Pandas, if possible.

Notes:
- The output index doesn't need to be labeled `index`.
- This doesn't have to be a pure Pandas solution.  For example, I looked a bit at some of the `sklearn` methods for handling sparsity, but none of them quite seemed appropriate for solving this task.
- I'm not sure this matters, but after this operation I merge the resulting `DataFrame` (call it `dense`) with another `DataFrame` (call this one `df`), using `dense` and `df` indices as merge keys.  So in this example, `vec` indices are `[0,1,2,3]`, and the output `dense` needs to retain those indices.

Comment: Do you have a chance to save your `vec` in a different format? What is your source data set? Is it a sparse matrix?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm stuck handling `vec` in the format it's in - it's coming to me from upstream processes that I don't have control over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `list comprehensions` - first for splitting and then convert it to `dicts` with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
print ([dict([y.split(':') for y in (x.split())]) for x in vec])
[{'83': '1.0000', '70': '1.0000', '71': '1.0000'}, 
 {'8': '2.0000', '3': '2.0000', '9': '3.0000'}, 
 {'185': '1.0000', '186': '1.0000', '3': '3.0000'}, 
 {'289': '1.0000', '8': '1.0000', '3': '1.0000'}]

df = pd.DataFrame([dict([y.split(':') for y in (x.split())]) for x in vec])
print (df)
      185     186     289       3      70      71       8      83       9
0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN  1.0000  1.0000     NaN  1.0000     NaN
1     NaN     NaN     NaN  2.0000     NaN     NaN  2.0000     NaN  3.0000
2  1.0000  1.0000     NaN  3.0000     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
3     NaN     NaN  1.0000  1.0000     NaN     NaN  1.0000     NaN     NaN
```

Get `DataFrame` with `NaN`s and strings, so for numeric casting is necessary:

```
print (type(df.loc[0,'70']))
<class 'str'>

df = df.astype(float)
print (df)
   185  186  289    3   70   71    8   83    9
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  3.0
2  1.0  1.0  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN

print (type(df.loc[0,'70']))
<class 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael.  Your solution is about two orders of magnitude faster than mine (5.52ms vs 648ms).  Really nice!

Comment: Glad can help! Nice weekend!